# Are there 5V battery packs available without a boost converter?

Tags: batteries, usb, 5v

Looking for a 5V portable power source without switching or conversion noise.

Comment: can you use a lantern battery and 5v LDO?

Comment: NiCd battery chemistry presents close to \$1.25\:\text{V}\$ for about half (or more) of its discharge cycle. Four of those would be very close to \$5\:\text{V}\$. But you've said nothing about what range of voltages are acceptable. So it is hard to know.

Comment: No battery has a native 5v output. Alkaline cells come in around 6V, Lipo is 3.7 or 7.2...

Comment: @MadHatter, an alkaline cell is typically about 1.5 V. A battery of 4 cells could make 6 V.

Comment: You could use 2x lithium and a linear regulator.  The reality though is that few things can't work from a switching regulator, it just needs to be a *good* switching regulator with good filtering, and that takes more attention.

Comment: @photon, your correct, I was just naming combinations that are commonly close to 5v.

Comment: A half charged LiPo in series with an alkaline would be about right, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Why are you worried about switching noise?

Comment: 4 alkaline cells is not a good solution. unless your prepared the throw them out when they are only half empty.

Answer (score 4):

> Looking for a 5V portable power source without switching or conversion noise.

Use anything, for example a 7.2 V Lithum-Ion pack, and a linear (non-switchmode) voltage regulator, which drops the 2.2 V "overvoltage", and converts them to heat.

That's a waste of energy (and hence, battery life), but it doesn't incur switching noise. If you're drawing significant currents, you might need to cool your linear regulator.

However, the way you ask this question suggests you don't actually want that, but more something that *is* a low-noise switching power supply. Just because the supply you've been using so far has terribly switching noise doesn't mean you can't build a good switch-mode-based supply!

In fact, in many, if not most, applications, a switch-mode power supply with good output filtering is sufficient. If really necessary (e.g. sensitive analog high-bandwidth measurement electronics), design the SMPS to generate a voltage slightly above the target voltage, and regulate with a good, noise-rejecting low-dropout regulator ("LDO") to the target voltage. That's how professional radio equipment does it.